# rar package not available ..?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, rar

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 on a machine I was trying to install 'rar' from the terminal, but I get an error that the package isn't 'available' .. !?

This is what I'm typing in:

`apt-get install rar`
`sudo apt-get install unrar`

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Package rar is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package rar has no installation candidate
```

I also updated the repositories using `apt-get update`, but still problem is not resolved ..

Where can I download this package from manually, so that I can then manually install it myself .. ?

Comment: Off topic, can't close from iPhone.

Answer (score 4):

try to install using that command
ubuntu:~# apt-get install unrar-free

Answer (score 0):

this question should be in : https://askubuntu.com/

second install `un-rar` package!

Comment: I did install package named 'unrar-free' from Synaptics, which made the `unrar` command available in terminal, but `rar` still didn't work ..

Comment: @Ahmad I installed rar package 6 month ago! I think you should install aptitude to install it! another way is install it from synaptic package manager

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out myself ...

I searched for 'rar' in Ubuntu Software Center (available in Ubuntu 10.04 at least, which I have), and it found the package I was looking for ..

But why didn't it install from the terminal still remains a mystery ..